# Request for FileIOPermisson fails

Tags: c#, file-io, file-permissions, grasshopper

I am experiencing some strange behavior with a custom component in Rhino/Grasshopper.
The code of the component is written in C# so I am assuming that the error is due to a standard .NET programming mistake I made.

I am getting the following error on some computers (it works just fine on others). I made sure that I was logged in a admin so that I have read/write access to the files. What could a possible source of that error be? Is there a special way to ask for permission?
Thank you very much in advance.

[image: Error message]

Comment: this looks like something that would be found in the .config file.. we need more information

Comment: hi thanks for you quick reply - this is a windows application. My custom component however is just a plugin (dll) for Grasshopper/Rhino4. To install the plugin you just place it in a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tool like [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to find out, which File you are trying to access. Afterwards you can take a look at the file and fix your code.

Comment: thanks for the hint.. i have not had a chance to use ProcMon yet but - do you have any idea why the same code works on one machine and not the other? The files are the same too... Also I can edit all the files with the explorer...The one that has issues is a more tightly controlled university pc but windows says that I have admin rights...

Comment: Ok running ProcMon I am getting a couple of NAME NOT FOUND and INVALID DEVICE REQUESTS. I dont really know what that means???

Comment: 4:14:46.1669523 PM Rhino4.exe 5508 CreateFile C:\UD_\temp\default NAME NOT FOUND Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
4:14:46.1671905 PM Rhino4.exe 5508 CreateFile C:\UD_\temp\default NAME NOT FOUND Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a